# Creating a Windows Menu Bar in Python

Tags: python, windows, drop-down-menu, menu

So, I have looked around Google, and here, I do get some interesting results, like using Tkinter and some example from YouTube videos, but I don't think I am asking the right question.

Basically, I want to create a GUI, in Python, and I want to be able to use the standard Windows drop-down menu.  By this I mean; File, Edit, Help, Etc.  Is there some sort of template to create this or do I need to create my own, using button configurations?

I am assuming I am missing a large portion of information, specifically relating to Windows manipulation, in my studies so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a GUI framework, there are several to choose from but personally I would say the main ones are:

- Tkinter *comes with python so nothing to download, looks "unixy"*
- [QT](http://www.qt.io/) & pyQT *very powerful, cross platform, big downloads, always looks QT*
- [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/) *Uses wrappers around native controls so small, fast, cross platform, looks native.*  Especially download & install the documents & examples package - gives you lots of code examples in the searchable demo that you can edit and run within the demo.

[image: Demo]

*I really should mention that my **personal** favorite is wxPython, as I have used it a lot over the years.*

Comment: "looks unixy" sounds like advice from the 90's. Modern Tkinter uses native widgets for many of the controls. It looks a lot like OSX apps on OSX, and a lot like Windows apps on Windows. And by using ttk, which comes with tkinter, you get more native widgets. I agree that wxPython looks a tad bit more modern, but at a slight cost (extra download, (arguably) harder to use, a bit less stable...).